# EKS coredns addon deployment resets after edit

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, coredns

I'm trying to tune the resources for coredns add-on in EKS (installed the add-on via aws) by running `kubectl edit deployment coredns`  and then editing the memory limit and request in the yaml file. the change applies for a couple of minutes but then it reverts by itself for no apparent reason. docs in aws don't show a way to edit those configurations from the add-on manager itself.
is there anything I'm missing? i've noticed the annotation for `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` always stays with the previous attributes no matter what i do so this may be a hint?

Comment: i ran `aws eks delete-addon --cluster-name my-cluster --addon-name coredns --preserve` on my cluster, the memory stopped reverting to the original value after that but now i can't manage this deployment with aws so this is not a good solution for me

Comment: Why do you need to change memory limits for `coreDNS`? Are you having any issues? AWS EKS managed kubernetes cluster and it's already set up in optimal ways.

Comment: What you did is to remove `coreDNS` from managing by AWS. This way you won't receive any security updates and etc. So it's not recommended approach.

Comment: @moonkotte I'm getting oomkilled issues on my coredns pods, i removed the management only for test to see if this is why it's getting reverted.

Comment: This is 100% the reason because when add-on is updated it will rewrite all changes, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-ons-configuration.html). As well as you can check which fields are managed by aws. If you're experiencing issues with coreDNS on a new cluster, then going to AWS support is the right option to me since it's managed kubernetes. CoreDNS itself can have [issues as well[(https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/3388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So The way to do it according to AWS is to either increase the replica count on the deployment which they apparently don't control in any way or to move to self managed coredns and control the memory values of the pods yourself.

probably can create an HPA resource that will scale the deployment accordingly though i would expect AWS to have one themselves for this purpose